# RLC specific current-time value

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, transpose

I previously asked this question and got the answer I was looking for

[Series RLC Circuit Step Response](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2256252/series-rlc-circuit-step-response/2256461#2256461)

I have a solution to a second order ODE that is

$ i(t) = A{\rm e}^{{S_1}t} + B{\rm e}^{{S_2}t} $

And again what I thought would be simple has me beaten, I want to calculate the t for specific values of I

So at what value of t do I get say 10A (for arguments sake)

Clearly there are going to be two solutions, rising edge and falling edge if you like

I have tried a lot of things but because A is negative then I cant take the Ln, so I treid swapping sides and it just got a bit hairy, I ended up with something that gave me an answer almost correct but only for the rising edge I think I need a quadratic with two solutions but I have no idea how I get that from the above!

Comment: Unless the values $S_1$ and $S_2$ are the same, you are gonna need a numerical solver to find a solution to $i(t) = i_0$ for $t$

Comment: S1 and S2 are not equal.So its an iterative process?, I can use Matlab in seconds to tell me the values (see the linked question) but I was wanting to do it on paper. I stumble across equations that require iterations in my job on a regular basis, I find it amazing how the simple things in life can be so damn hard even designing a simple heatsink its the same thing!

Comment: A and B are equal but ones positive the other negative so it goes to A(e^s2t -e^s1t). looks easy doesnt it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be analytically solved for some values of $S_1$ and $S_2$, for instance if $S_2 = 2S_1$ then, the time $t$ at which you get the current $i$ is

$$
t(i) = \frac{1}{S_1}\ln \left(\frac{A + \sqrt{A^2 -4Ai}}{2A} \right)
$$

You can also solve it for $S_2 = 3S_1$, but it gets complicated very quickly. Instead I suggest you to use Newton's method to calculate $t$:

- Start with a reasonable assumption for $t_0$
- Iterate
  $$
  t_{k+1} = t_k - \frac{A(e^{S_1 t} - e^{S_2 t}) - i_{\rm target}}{A(S_1e^{S_1 t} -S_2 e^{S_2 t})}
  $$

until $i(t_k) \approx i_{\rm target}$

**EDIT**

In the situation $S_2 = 2 S_1$, call $x = e^{S_1 t}$ such that $x^2 = e^{2S_1 t} = e^{S_2 t}$, then the equation can be written as

$$
i = Ax-Ax^2 ~~~\Rightarrow~~~ Ax^2 -Ax + i = 0
$$

whose solution is

$$
x = \frac{A + \sqrt{A^2 - 4A i}}{2A}  = e^{S_1 t}
$$

Taking $\ln$ at both sides we get to

$$
S_1 t = \ln \left( \frac{A + \sqrt{A^2 - 4A i}}{2A} \right)
$$

Comment: B = -A, can you show me how you arrived at your equation please, like I said I flipped things around and ended up with an equation (which I doubt makes mathematical sense) but I think it was just a fluke the solution wasnt exact, it was 4.27us where as the value from Matlab was 4.67us. i am especially interested to see where that square root came from. Doing iterations on paper I find is no fun at all, isnt that what C programming was invented for =~)